# Best way to clean and store files

Tags: csv, pandas

Our employees are doing work for clients, and the clients send us files which contain information that we turn into performance metrics (we do not have direct access to this information - it needs to be sent from the clients). These files are normally .csv or .xlsx so typically I read them with pandas and output a much cleaner, smaller file.

1) Some files contain call drivers or other categorical information which repeats constantly (for example, Issue Driver 1 with like 20 possibilities and Issue Driver 2 with 100 possibilities) - these files are about 100+ million records per year so they become pretty large if I consolidate them. Is it better to create a dictionary and map each driver out to an integer? I read a bit about the category dtype in pandas - does this make output file sizes smaller too or just in-memory?

2) I store the output as .csv which means that I lose the dtypes if I ever read the file again. How do I maintain dtypes and should I save the files to sqlite instead perhaps instead of massive .csv files? My issue now is that I literally create codes to break the files up into separate .csvs per month and then maintain a massive file which I use for analysis (dump it into Tableau normally). If I need to to make changes to the monthly files I have to re-write them all which is slow on my laptops non-SSD hard drive.

3) I normally only need to share data with one or two people. And most analysis requests are adhoc but involve like one - three years worth of very granular data (individual surveys or interactions each represented by a single row in separate files). In other words I do not need a system with high concurrency of read-write. Just want something fast, efficient, and consolidated.

Comment: pandas is in-memory. Why not have a translation table, of ints -> drivers, and store the drivers as ints. I recommend pytables/HDF5Store rather than csvs.

Comment: So if I created a translation table called drivers.csv, would I easily be able to 1) convert the drivers to their corresponding integer without using .map and manually typing each one, 2) convert them back to drivers when needed? What is the best way to go about that efficiently? 

I'll read up on HDF5Store, I am unfamiliar.